# How do i use wildcards in selectors in testcafe

Tags: regex, testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

Hello I want to know how do I use wildcards with selectors in testcafe, for example, I have several Id in a page which is as below

```
'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl02_imgBtnFilter'
'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl04_imgBtnFilter'
'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl09_imgBtnFilter'
```

The starting remains the same [ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_] and the ending remains the same [_imgBtnFilter] but the number ct*** keeps changing.

So I want to put a wildcard in that place and I want to know if there is an option of doing that in TestCafe?

Comment: Did you try with regular expressions?  https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions in your selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withattribute) as @Janaaaa mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Alex! Here is what i tried: The HTML is as <input type="image" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ctl29_imgBtnClearFilter" title="Clear Filter" ... the ct129 keeps changing as this is dynamic. SO if I am using Regular expression  I am writing this as const Sel =Selector('input').withAttribute(/id/,/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gv_ct[0-200]_imgBtnClearFilter/); however this is not working !!! where am i going wrong?

Comment: Your regular expression does not seem to be correct. Use one of the free online regex services to test your regular expression.